# How to use a single query with a varying WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE  location1 = true
```

The users table has 4 columns:

```
location1
location2
location3
location4
```

In my stored procedure, I want to pass in a parameter that will tell me to use either location1, or location2 etc.

Is there a way to write my query so that I can handle this without having to re-write the same query 4 times for each where filter?

My SELECT query is a little more complicated but essentially it is the same idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some `OR`s to accomplish that (especially if you don't want to go the dynamic sql route).

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE  ((@myLocationParameter = 'location1' AND location1 = true)
        OR (@myLocationParameter = 'location2' AND location2 = true)
        OR ....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dynamic query`

```
Declare @column varchar(128), -- Procedure input
        @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE  '+quotename(@column)+' = true'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```